# Не видит System.out.print в новом классе

Tags: java, intellij-idea, классы

Пользуюсь Intellij Idea. При создании нового класса (не `main`) не работает команда `System.out.print`. Компилятор пишет, что не может решить символ. В классе с методом `main` все работает. Не пойму в чем дело.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может быть потому, что надо вызывать это в методе а не сразу в классе? :-D

Comment: Да, именно в этом суть дела

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы объявляете класс и сразу же пишите вызов метода `System.out.print()` - это недопустимо. Использование метода возможно в инициализаторе, конструкторе или другом методе:

```
public class sfe {
  {
    System.out.print(""); // в инициализаторе.
  }

  public sfe() {
    System.out.print(""); // в конструкторе.
  }

  public void print() {
    System.out.print(""); // в другом методе.
  }
}
```

Comment: Большое человеческое спасибо!